# How to access template parameter from specialized member function?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T, int N>
class A
{
public:
    void func();
};
template<typename T, int N>
void A<int, N>::func()
{
    printf("%d\n", N);
}
int main()
{
    A<int, 3> a;
    a.func();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this piece of code, g++ gives these errors:

```
test.cpp:10:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class A<int, N>’
test.cpp:4:7: error: declaration of ‘class A<int, N>’
```

I've only managed to compile this when A::func isn't specialized at all and when the function is also specialized for N.

How do I specialize A::func for T and access N (which should be able to be any value), too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this was possible, the syntax would have to be

```
template<int N>
void A<int, N>::func()
{
    printf("%d\n", N);
}
```

I.e., `T` would not be mentioned in the template parameter list.

But unfortunately, it isn't possible. Individual functions (including member functions) cannot be partially specialized.

From the Standard (in the section about partial class template specializations):

> (§14.5.5/2) Each class template partial specialization is a distinct template and deﬁnitions shall be provided for the members of a template partial specialization (14.5.5.3).

In your situation, the most direct way to accomplish what you need would therefore be to partially-specialize the entire class template:

```
template<int N>
class A<int,N>
{
public:
  void func();
};

template<int N>
void A<int,N>::func()
{
    printf("%d\n",3);
}
```

[Working example of this on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f2de1bee0b17829c0bd00f3635d47cb4-881e2521f19ab33cbc733b5d83fdd598) (Of course, the definition of `func` could be inlined into the class template definition.)

But this might not be optimal when the class template has many other members, since you would have to redefine them all:

> (§14.5.5/3) [...] A class template specialization is a distinct template. The members of the class template partial specialization are unrelated to the members of the primary template. Class template partial specialization members that are used in a way that requires a deﬁnition shall be deﬁned; the deﬁnitions of members of the primary template are never used as deﬁnitions for members of a class template partial specialization. [...]

In some cases it is preferable to declare a separate class template with just this one function as member (possibly a static member, if no access to other members is required – possibly passing members to which access *is* required as explicit function arguments), and then refer to that from within the actual class template (to avoid having to partially-specialize the entire class template).

Comment: Are you sure that's the relevant quote?

Comment: @jrok It is relevant, but it may not be the only relevant one. I am still looking for one that says explicitly that there is no way to partially-specialize an individual member. (There may not be any such statement, though.)

Comment: OP is not specializing a member, `func` is not a template. The problem here is that the class template partial specialization isn't defined at the point where OP tries to define `func` member of that specialization. If we define the partial specialization, then [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2b153beb291c2859b6de86f971c64881-0be4386eb9b168939a6a7d681c02387e).

Comment: Nice, thorough answer. Accepted.

Comment: @jogojapan On second reading, though, I see what you're saying, and yes, the quote seems to be relevant :) +1

Comment: @jrok Yes.. right, I had read the code as an attempt to partially specialize just one member. But you could, alternatively, read it as an attempt to define a member of a partially specialized class before declaring that class.